# Get Os and Country flag from IP

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a website where you give someone the link of a website and it returns the IP and much information, such as the flag of the country and the OS. For the country flag I searched and I find this website: http://hostip.info/

And my code was:

```
 <IMG SRC="http://api.hostip.info/flag.php?ip= ip here " ALT="IP Address Lookup">
```

But it didn't work it returns just empty block. And for the OS I searched and I can't find anything but as you see in this website it gives the OS of any website:

http://www.zone-h.org/archive

Does anyone have the solution? I think the solution would be in PHP.

Comment: Geolocation by IP address is notoriously unreliable. You'll get best results from a paid service. You can't get the operating system from an IP address. You might be able to extract it from the http headers  but only if the sending machine obligingly adds it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<img src="http://api.hostip.info/flag.php?ip=153.50.106.161" alt="IP Address Lookup">
```

Tested it via random ip 153.50.106.161 from [ip test generator](http://sqa.fyicenter.com/Online_Test_Tools/Test_IP_Address_Generator.php)

About the OS, i found some [useful tutorial](http://subinsb.com/php-identify-remote-os) via PHP/JSON (didn't try it but they got [live demo](http://demos.subinsb.com/php/identify-remote-os/) which i believe its working).

Comment: it works but what for the os ?